# How to call java method from JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to add functionality in JSP page that is if following order is in ascending order of date then click on above button will change to descending order of date and vice versa. That's dates appeared on screen based on search keyword by user.
 By Default its coming in descending order, did code in java. (Existing functionality)

[image]

```
private Map<String,String> processMapForSorting(Map<String,String> keyNumber,Map<String,String> dateMap) {
        Map<String,String> list1=new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        DateUtil dateUtil=new DateUtil();
        Map<String,String> sortedDateMap=dateUtil.sortMapOnDateKey(dateMap);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sortedDateMap.entrySet()) {
            list1.put(entry.getKey(),"Date: "+entry.getValue()+"        "+keyNumber.get(entry.getKey()));
        }
        return list1;
    }



    public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortMapOnDateKey( Map<K, V> map)
    {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
            {
                return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
            }
        } );
```

In above if we replace with o1 to o2 and o2 to o1 then it will come to in ascending order. Now, problem is how to implement on JSP page. Ajax might be helpful if we don't want to reload the page again. But its fine if we reload the page. I don't know how to do it via java script or Jquery or JSTL? I have limited knowledge on UI related stuff.

Comment: try this http://tablesorter.com/docs/ - standard UI stuff

Answer (score 0):

In JSP you can use DWR (Direct Web Remoting) http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html to achieve ajax.

> DWR is a Java library that enables Java on the server and JavaScript
>   in a browser to interact and call each other as simply as possible.
>   DWR is Easy Ajax for Java

See More on :
http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/getting-started.html
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/jsp/step-by-step-dwr-application-simple-ajax-in-java/

Comment: @Bhuwan: Thanks for your inputs.I don't have permission to download any jars and all. I have to ask my superior for that. Its little bit time consuming. I will do that..! Mean while do you have any other way to achieve this with out Ajax so can at least try with that.